# How to make PyTest use the `conftest.py` of a parent directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pytest

I am working on a suite of tests for a project that were not written by me. The way they were set up is as follows

```
root/
   conftest.py
   testType1/
      a.py
   testType2/
   etc.
```

The file `a.py` is as follows

```
class TestClass:
    value_thats_important = None

    def test_to_test(self):
        do work that uses self.value_thats_important
```

Heres the problem I am encountering, the way it was originally developer, `self.value_thats_important` is set during the `conftest.py` generate tests. So if I run

```
pytest root/ arg=ARG_THAT_I_NEED
```

or

```
pytest testType1/ arg=ARG_THAT_I_NEED
```

It works totally fine. However, I also need to be able to run the test individually without calling every other test, and when I run

```
pytest testType1/a.py::TestClass arg=ARG_THAT_I_NEED
```

I get the error that `Nonetype not subscriptable`, which is telling me that the conftest is not getting called. I'm pretty new to pytest so is there a way I can salvage this without having to rewrite the entire test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a job for [fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html). The details will vary based on the specifics of your implementation, so here's a toy example that demonstrates the functionality.

Directory structure

```
tests/
   conftest.py
   testType1/
      a.py
```

**tests/conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def my_arg():
    yield "foo"
```

**tests/testType1/a.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("my_arg")
class TestClass():
    value_thats_important = None

    def test_to_test(self,my_arg):
        self.value_thats_important = my_arg

        assert self.value_thats_important == "foo"
```

Running the test

```
PS myproj\tests\testType1> pytest -v a.py
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- myproj\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: myproj\tests\testType1
collected 1 item

a.py::TestClass::test_to_test PASSED
```